# Error in VS2015 while trying to generate scaffolded API controller

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm trying to generate scaffolded components in my testing solution. I right click in my project and click on "Add scaffolded item" then I select "API controller with actions from Entity framework". There I select my model class and context and when I click on Add, it throws the following error:

> Error
>   There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unhandled exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Codegeneration.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60', at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools.Program.Main(String [] args)'

I'm convinced that is caused by a problem in the dependencies of the solution. So far I've tried by including the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core library but does not solve the problem.

Those are the dependencies on my project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.1-prerelease-10020",
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design": "1.1.1-prerelease-10020",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core": "1.1.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's caused by wrong versions in dependencies and uncompatible code generators for the platform.

Opening/converting the project to VS2017 community and comparing with a blank new one for VS2017 shows the problem. I forced VS2015 to work on .Net Core 1.1.1 and code generators versions where not available.

The wrong:

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.1-prerelease-10020" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.1-prerelease-10020" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
```

The right:

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.1-prerelease-10020" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.1-prerelease-10020" />
```